# How to use a std::string without copying?

Tags: c++, string, stl, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have a class say,

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      void ProcessString(std::string &buffer)
      {
          // perform operations on std::string

          // call other functions within class
          // which use same std::string string
      }

      void Bar(std::string &buffer)
      {
          // perform other operations on "std::string" buffer
      }

      void Baz(std::string &buffer)
      {
          // perform other operations on "std::string" buffer
      }
};
```

This class tries to use a `std::string` buffer to perform operations on it using various methods under these conditions:

- I don't want to pass a copy of `std::string` which I already have.
- I don't want to create multiple objects of this class.

For example:

```
// Once an object is created
Foo myObject;

// We could pass many different std::string's to same method without copying
std::string s1, s2, s3;
myObject.ProcessString(s1);
myObject.ProcessString(s2);
myObject.ProcessString(s3);
```

I could use the string and assign it as a class member so that other functions using can know about it.

But it seems we cannot have a reference class member `std::string &buffer` because it can only be initialized from constructor.

I could use a pointer to `std::string` i.e. `std::string *buffer` and use it as a class member and then pass the addresses of `s1, s2, s3`.

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      void ProcessString(std::string *buf)
      {
          // Save pointer
          buffer = buf;

          // perform operations on std::string

          // call other functions within class
          // which use same std::string string
      }

      void Bar()
      {
          // perform other operations on "std::string" buffer
      }

      void Baz()
      {
          // perform other operations on "std::string" buffer
      }
   private:
       std::string *buffer;
};
```

Or, the other way could be pass each functions a reference to `std::string` buffer just as **shown in the first example above**.

Both ways kind of seem a bit ugly workarounds to be able to use a `std::string` without copying as I have rarely seen the usage of std::string as a pointer or pass all the functions of class the same argument.

Is there a better around this or what I'm doing is just fine?

Comment: You are already using the string without copying. You are passing by reference, i.e. std::string &s.

Comment: Should I do the same for other functions such as `Baz` and `Bar` as well? or maybe have a class member pointer to let other functions know about it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't worry about string copying too much. What's the problem with it? And I've not understood why you don't just pass the string by reference to `Bar` and `Baz` as well.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The problem is mostly performance, copying an object is expensive CPU and memory-wise, and also the fact you cannot modify an object in the caller [without replacing it completely] unless you pass it by pointer or reference.

Comment: @cpx It seems to me you already have pretty much what you want as cageman pointed out. Its not clear to me what remains to be a problem here.

Comment: @Havenard: Performance problems with string copying are often imagined. That's not to say that they don't exist, just that their existence typically has to be proven by measuring. It would not be surprising if reading a big string from a file, database or network connection was much slower than copying it in your program a few thousand times.

Comment: Sir I have copied enough strings in my noob ages to know it does cause performance drags, serious ones depending on how intensive you work with strings. I know what I'm talking about here.

Comment: I have edited the question to avoid the confusion with only one function taking a reference. Later in the question I've asked would it better all functions taking a reference/pointer or shall I keep a pointer to string as a class member.

Comment: @Havenard: As I said, I do not dispute that string copying *can* cause performance problems. I do, however, dispute the claim that this is a frequent problem in the majority of application domains.

Comment: so, with the update, how r u supposed to use the string variables outside of the class?

Comment: @cpx  but now it's confusing, because it's not clear where the object gets it's string.  From the constructor ?  And your example is still using the old function signature.

Comment: @Christophe confusing for sure.

Comment: I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: @cpx You pretty much covered all options. You either pass the buffer as parameter (which is the most correct, because the buffer does not belong to `Foo`), or keep a pointer to it as a class property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keeping in MyObject a reference or a pointer to a string which is not ownned by your object is dangerous.  It will be easy to get ***nasty undefined behaviour***.

Look at the following legal example (Bar is public):

```
myObject.ProcessString(s1);     // start with s1 and keep its address
myObject.Bar();                 // works with s1 (using address previously stored)
```

Look at the following UB:

```
if (is_today) {
    myObject.ProcessString(string("Hello"));  // uses an automatic temporary string
}                                             // !! end of block: temporary is destroyed!
else {
    string tmp = to_string(1234);            // create a block variable 
    myObject.ProcessString(tmp);             // call the main function 
}                                            // !! end of block:  tmp is destroyed
myObject.Bar();  // expects to work with pointer, but in reality use an object that was already destroyed !!  => UB
```

The errors are very nasty, because when reading function's usage, everything seems ok and well managed.  The problem is hidden by automatic destruction of bloc variables.

So if you really want to avoid the copy of the string, you could use a pointer as you envisaged,  but you shall only use this pointer in functions called directly by ProcessString(), and make these functions private.

In all other case, I'd strongly suggest to reconsider your position, and envisage:

- a local copy of the string in the object that shall use it.
- Or use a `string&` parameters in all the object's function that need it.  This avoids the copies but leaves to caller the responsibility of organising the proper management of the string.

Answer (score 6):

You basically need to answer this question: who owns the string? Does `Foo` own the string? Does the external caller own the string? Or do they both share ownership of the string.

"Owning" the string means that the lifetime of the string is tied to it. So if Foo owns the string, the string will stop existing when Foo stops existing or destroys it. Shared ownership is far more complicated, but we can make it simpler by saying that the string will exist as long as any of the owners keep it.

Each situation has a different answer:

1. `Foo` owns the string: Copy the string into `Foo`, then let the member methods mutate it.
2. External resource owns the string: `Foo` should never hold a reference to the string outside of its own stack, since the string could be destroyed without its knowledge. This means that it needs to be passed by reference to every method that uses it and does not own it, even if the methods are in the same class.
3. Shared ownership: Use a `shared_ptr` when creating the string, then pass that shared_ptr to every instance that shares ownership. You then copy the shared_ptr to a member variable, and methods access it. This has much higher overhead then passing by reference, but if you want shared ownership it is one of the safest ways to do so.

There are actually several other kinds of ways to model ownership, but they tend to be more esoteric. Weak ownership, transferable ownership, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is that

> 1.I don't want to pass a copy of std::string which I already have.
>
> 2.I don't want to create multiple objects of this class.

using pass by ref would be the solution to 1
using static would be the solution to 2. since it is a static memeber method, there would be only one copy of this method. it wont belong to any object, though. With that being said, you can call this method directly instead of through an object.

For example,

```
class Foo
{
      static void ProcessString(std::string &s)
      {
          // perform operations on std::string

          // call other functions within class
          // which use same std::string string
      }

}
```

when you call this method, it would be something like this:

```
std::string s1, s2, s3;
Foo::ProcessString(s1);
Foo::ProcessString(s2);
Foo::ProcessString(s3);
```

One step further, if you want only one instance of this class, you can refer to singleton design pattern.

Comment: *"if you want only one instance of this class, you can refer to singleton design pattern."* Here is an easier pattern if you want only one instance of the class: `Foo f;`

Comment: I'm not even convinced that a class is required at all.  Why not just a `namespace`?

Comment: it could be for whatever reason, which is out of this question's scope. all in all, the code meets the requirement of the user. @AndreKostur

Comment: @ChristianHackl not quite sure what u r saying, though. without using singleton, multiple instances of this class r possible.

Comment: @STNYU: My comment was quite sarcastic, of course. You will find that Singleton tends to be considered an anti-pattern nowadays; it's really an obfuscated global variable. You will find tons of material on that topic on SO and other sites. In essence, the sheer idea of a *class* which allows only one single instance is a contradiction in itself. The word "class" means: *something of which many instances can exist*. If multiple instances of a class hurt you for some reason, then better fix that reason. And if you still don't want multiple instances, just don't create them.